# Ajax asp.net throws internal server error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, silverlight

Here is the html and code but it is not working. Can any of you help me get through this?

```
    function changeVideoSrc(title, videoLink) {
        document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = 'Now Playing ... ' + title;
        scroll();
        alert('{"videoSrc" : "' + videoLink + '",title" : "' + title + '"}');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'test.aspx/changeWebcamSource',
            data: '{"videoSrc" : "' + videoLink + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.d.toString() == "success")
                    alert("Video Source Changed Successfully.");
                else
                    alert("Fail to Update Video Source.");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (textStatus == 'timeout')
                    alert('timeout');
                alert(errorThrown.toString());
            }
        });
    }

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string changeWebcamSource(String videoSrc, String title)
{
    try
    {
        lblNowPlaying.Text = title;
        mediaInitParams.Attributes.Add("value",
            "selectedcaptionstream=textstream_eng,mediaurl=" + videoSrc);
        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "failure";
    }
}

<object id="slObj" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
                    width="100%" height="350">
                    <param name="source" value="SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap" />
                    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                    <param name="background" value="white" />
                    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
                    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                    <param name="InitParams" id="mediaInitParams" runat="server" value="" />
                    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                            style="border-style: none" />
                    </a>
                </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes and try

```
data: {videoSrc : videoLink,title: '' },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two parameters in webmethod but you are only passing one from ajax call you are missing value of second parameter and instead of passing values in quotes try to pass data using stringify like this

```
data: JSON.stringify({'videoSrc':videoLink,'title':'Your title here'}),
```

Comment: It is not needed to stringify the json. And yes I have forgot to add a title there. The reason behind the error was I was not adding the jquery library file to the page. Thank you.